# VoiceXML script runs fine on gist.github.com but won't run on my server

Tags: vxml, voicexml, vonage

I have a VoiceXML script that works fine when I call to it on gist.github.com - https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jpelton/6bb484628f3bb3ef9cd1/raw/gistfile1.txt but when I call to the exact same VoiceXML script on my own server (https://mobile-text-alerts.com/3.0/system/nexmo/recordMessage.php) the phone just rings twice and hangs up. The scripts appear to be exactly the same.

Is there some header value that is necessary that I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue where my phone provider (http://nexmo.com) was not trusting my comodo signed SSL certificate. I sent them to http://mobile-text-alerts.com/3.0/system/nexmo/recordMessage.php instead of https and it "fixed" the issue (until I get a new certificate).